# Javascript print with styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing-web-page

I'd like to ask if there's an option to print(send to printer) in js some part of website with css styles ?

I've created code:

```
  let print_area = window.open();
print_area.document.write(print_div.innerHTML);
  print_area.document.close();
  print_area.focus();
  print_area.print();
  print_area.close();
```

it prints exactly what I want, but I have no css styles there(but I've created media print)

my project on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/z58pr1fL/

Comment: Hi ! Please provide us **here** a snippet `<>` (and not volatile external content) of what you need and what you tried, it up to you ! ;)

Comment: _"but I've created media print"_ - but you have not injected it into the _new_ document you are opening there.

Answer (score 0):

I advice to create a css file for printer and insert this:

```html
(…)
<head>
   (…)
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css" />
   (…)
</head>
(…)
```

Inside this `print.css` subtract lots of colors as you can. Just for save inks in your users :)

Keep only border of your elements and texts with the shades of grey.

You could create a button for send to user's printer like this:

```
  <button type="button" onClick="window.print()">
```

or the best way is

```
  <button type="button" onClick="./path/of/javascript/files/printer.js">
```

printer.js

```
'use strict'
window.print();
```

If you not convince, try `window.print()` in your console.